# Migrate "Contact lists" from Thunderbird to Evolution

Tags: thunderbird, migration, evolution

I successfully migrated from Thunderbird to Evolution, including all my contacts.  However, the "Contact lists" or "Mailing lists" I created in Thunderbird have not migrated. By "Contact lists" or "Mailing lists", I mean that out of the thousands of contacts I successfully migrated, I had created groups of them in Thunderbird.  For instance, I could simply type 'family' in the to: field and all the members of my family would expand.

I doubt that the migrating "Contact lists" feature exists, but I ask, in case I missed something.